# My Character’s arms disappear in game

Tags: game-engine

This question is in continuation from my first question. I have solved the physics issue by having a tiny box at the character’s feet. But now i have problem when it comes to the FPS setup. See the following images:

[image: Arm rig]
[image: One arm missing.]
[image: Both arms present.]
[image: Both arms missing.]

I have managed to set my FPS camera view and set it up with the arms and gun. However as I move my mouse when testing the game to look at different angles, the arms sometimes disappear. Sometimes one of the arms, sometimes both, as seen in images. This is not what I intended and I am unsure what this a result of.

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this? Feel free to ask me any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure that this will work for you...
But weeks ago, I faced a similar problem and after some digging, I found out that some parts of my model were disappearing because I had some **Un-Applied Modifiers**..

Just Check the **Modifier** tap in the **Properties** panel and hit apply on any existing modifiers..

**EXCEPT FOR THE ARMATURE MODIFIER!!**

please report back if this worked, *otherwise upload the .blend file if you can!*

[image]